# How to translate SVG by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, translation

I'm a total beginner in coding, so please excuse this simple question.

I have an HTML file with an SVG in it:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="example.svg" width="1000" height="700" >
</body>

</html>
```

I need the following: A Javascript function which translates the SVG by 100px along the y-axis. How does such a function concretely have to look like?

Remarks: It must be Javascript. The SVG could also be included by the object-tag (instead of img). I need jquery at some other point, that's why it is loaded.

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

**EDIT:** What I have done so far. The HTML is included as iframe in an other project. The goal is to show a "specific part" of the SVG when the JS is triggered. I tried the following code in the head of the HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  window.parent.translation = function()
{ 
window.scrollTo(0, 100);
}
});
```

This would solve my problem and works everywhere perfectly fine - except for ipads. Whatever I did I could not scroll or jump to an anchor on ipads. That`s why I want to translate the SVG now (instead of scrolling the page). The effect should be the same.

So I tried to add an ID to the SVG as follows:

```
<img id="example_svg" src="example.svg" width="1000" height="700" >
```

And then I replaced the line with "scrollTo" by the following code:

```
document.getElementById('example_svg').style.setProperty("top", "100px");
```

But this doesn't work. So that's the point where I need help (alternatively scrollTo would be fine if it worked on ipads - but none of the workarounds I found in the internet worked).

Comment: Sorry, the closing <object> tag was just a typo. Yes, I wrote several JS functions (loops etc.) but haven't ever translated an SVG. I think I would find the image element by getElementbyId. The image element has to be located at x=0, y=0 at the beginning and then just translated by javascript. That's all. The JS will be triggered from outside (the whole HTML is included as an iframe in an other project).

Comment: OK, I added an bold "EDIT" in my posting above. There are more details and what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take the `<img>` out of the normal flow (ie shift it on the page relative to everything else), then you need to make it a "positioned" element.  You do that using the `position` CSS property.

You could use `position: relative`, or `position: absolute`. You may need to choose one over the other depending on your situation.  In the simple demo below, either would work.

```js
var thing = document.getElementById("thing");

thing.style.top = "100px";
```

```css
img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img id="thing" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" width="400" height="200" >
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works perfectly fine. I didn't know that I had to make it a positioned element. Thank you for the explanations!